# Relation between submodules of an $L$-module and ideals of $L$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

From previous posts, I can see that the ideals of a Lie algebra $L$ are exactly the submodules of $L$ when we make a Lie algebra $L$ into an $L$-module via the adjoint homomorphism. But I am trying to understand if this holds for a general module $V$. Given a Lie algebra $L$ and an $L$-module $V$, can we say that the submodules of $V$ are exactly the ideals of the Lie algebra $L$?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense: the submodules of $V$ are subsets of $V$, whereas the ideals of $L$ are subsets of $L$. How can they possibly be equal?

Comment: I am still new to Lie algebra and Representation Theory. I have been studying Representation of a Lie algebra for my undergraduate project for less than three months. Would that make sense if I say submodules of $L$ instead of $V$?

Comment: Yes, it would.${}$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183540/show-that-submodules-of-l-are-precisely-the-ideals-of-l?rq=1). If $V$ is not the adjoint module, we do not have such a relation.